# Can I listen to individual value changes in a Firestore Document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, listener

I read the [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) and wonder if I can listen for changes on a `Document` value or I must listen for changes to the `Document` (all values)

Lets say I have a Document:

```
{
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
}
```

And I only interested if `country` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore listeners respond to changes to a document. There is no way to only listen to a change to a specific field within the document(s).

If you have a specific use-case where the document is prohibitively large, you could consider putting the field into separate, additional documents for this use-case.